# compute FX forward from broker's data

Tags: volatility, fx, forward, delta

assume I have following delta-term vol data from broker:

```
Spot 3.4550
                 O/N      1WK      2WK      3WK      1M       6WK      2M
Volatility       7.544    7.7      7.731    7.911    8.025    8.18     8.4
Forward Points   0.0004   0.0021   0.0045   0.0063   0.0079   0.0106   0.0164
EUR Depo Rate    0.405    1.205    1.145    1.128    1.1      1.11     1.13
PLN Depo Rate    4.216    5.028    4.586    4.187    3.558    3.58     3.626
Butterfly        0.157    0.19     0.229    0.268    0.34     0.368    0.44
RiskReversal     0.35     0.45     0.567    0.683    0.9      0.983    1.2
```

is this for sure that $f=S+Forward Points$ so

$f_{ON}=3.4550+ 0.0004=3.4554$

$f_{1M}=3.4550+ 0.0079=3.4629$

and so on, **regardless** delta quoting convensions and ATM convensions

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking.  Are you just asking the quoting convention of forward points?

Comment: do you have any idea about delta quoting convension for FX options? I am asking about the computation of forward price, if the formula is true regardless of delta quoting convension, so I can compute it as described without any Depo Rate manipulation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're asking what the **FX Outright** for 1M EUR/PLN is, given that table, then yes the answer is just outright = spot + fwd points, which is 3.4550 + 0.0079 = 3.4629 (you had the wrong column for your 1M value).

Usually fwd points are quoted directly (i.e. not as an outright), using a divisor set by market convention. I expect EUR/PLN divisor to be 10,000, so that would be quoted as 79 pts.

So no, you don't need any of the rest of the data in the table.

Comment: thank you very much. I need rest data to construct full vol surface

Comment: To know what divisor you need to use, the easiest is to look at the # of digits in the FX spot on Reuters, the pips will be added to the same precision.

Comment: @BlueTrin could you give some example?

Comment: @cf16: literally go on Reuters, or on their webpage, if you do not have Reuters EIKON. Look at EURUSD, you will see a quote like 1.3060. This means that the pips have to be divided by 10000 because (by convention) they are added to the last digits of the FX quote ...